# The Shaman wandering spirit Lore's Arcane Enlightenment hex grants bonus arcane spells. Is there a spell level limit to what spells can be chosen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, spellcasting, shaman, spirits

The Shaman wandering spirit [Lore](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman/spirits/lore/)'s Arcane Enlightenment hex grants bonus arcane spells. Is there a spell level limit to what spells can be chosen?

The Arcane Enlightenment hex says:

> The shaman’s native intelligence grants her the ability to tap into
>   arcane lore. The shaman can add a number of spells from the
>   sorcerer/wizard spell list equal to her Charisma modifier (minimum 1)
>   to the list of shaman spells she can prepare. **To cast these spells
>   she must have an Intelligence score equal to at least 10 + the spell’s
>   level**, but the saving throw DCs of these spells are based on her
>   Wisdom rather than Intelligence. When she casts these spells, they are
>   treated as divine rather than arcane. Each time the shaman gains a
>   level after taking this hex, she can choose to replace one of these
>   spells for a new spell on the wizard/sorcerer spell list.

Emphasis mine.

The only limit seems to be on casting the spells. Does this mean you choose all high-level spells, but are limited by the level of spells you can cast as a shaman?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no limit, but choosing higher-level spells won’t do you much good until you get high enough in level to actually prepare them. The hex doesn’t give the shaman the high-level spell slots they need to prepare them, so as much as they “can” prepare them, assuming a high enough Intelligence, they still need slots to prepare them in and they haven’t got any until they’re high enough level anyway.

So sure, a 2nd-level shaman is welcome to take *arcane enlightenment* and choose to include *time stop* in their list of sorcerer/wizard spells to add to their spell list, but until they reach 17th level and can actually prepare and cast 9th-level spells, having *time stop* on their spell list doesn’t do them a lot of good. (Theoretically, it would enable them to cast *time stop* from a staff that had it, or to cast a *scroll of time stop* with a relatively-easy caster level check instead of the relatively-more-difficult Use Magic Device check, but those would be the only benefits.)